# When I Pack my tkinter widget in single line it garbage collected, why?

Tags: python, tkinter

If I use the code below like

```
photo_label = Label(root, image=photos[0]).pack()
```

and print(type(photo_label)) it come up nonetype but if use it seperated like below then it's a tkinter label. why this happening?

```
photo_label = Label(root, image=photos[0])
photo_label.pack()
```

Comment: It is because `.pack()` returns `None`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: @acw1668 thank you I never thought of that. Thank you very much